# Will LG 29UM58 run smoothly on Nvidia GTX260

Tags: graphics-card, display, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card

Will the monitor LG 29UM58 run smoothly on Nvidia GTX260?

The specification of Nvidia GTX260 says it supports resolution up to `2560x1440`, however I am wondering how smooth it will run as far as watching movies, text editing (Word) and image editing is considered. I am currently using resolution `1440x900 60Hz` which runs smoothly and which would get upgraded to `2560x1080 60Hz`

Comment: Of course your CPU will also have an effect.  Has it been upgraded more recently than the graphics?  You're talking about a GPU which is now seven generations old, it won't have hardware acceleration for newer video codecs, which means more CPU burden.

Comment: @BenVoigt The CPU is Intel Q8200.